# How does angular momentum get quantized?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, representation-theory, discrete

We know that the magnitude and direction of angular momentum is quantized in quantum mechanics. We can explain the quantization with the help of quantum numbers. But actually who is responsible for this quantization? What is the significance of the reference direction? Can we take any arbitrary direction as the reference axes while considering space quantization? The angular momentum will  be oriented in a particular direction (angle) with reference axis, then how other orientations are possible? ( as explained by different magnetic quantum numbers).

Comment: Boy, if we could find out just who was responsible for quantization we could make physics much simpler...

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29655/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22806/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/174018/2451 and links therein.

Comment: There are very dedicated people here who unfortunately do not understand that it is the new members who keep the forum alive. It's unwise to take away the desire to ask questions from a new forist from the beginning.    +1